# How to deploy/reference built files in Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines, webdeploy, msdeploy

I have created a pipeline in Azure DevOps. First it restores Nuget, then it builds the solution with the following arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\" /p:IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination=False
```

This all works fine. The next task is to publish to my Azure App Service and I use a MSDeploy Package Sync task to do this. I do not know what to set the 'Web Deploy Package' field to, in order for it to pick up the artefacts built. When I run the pipeline it always fails on that task with a DirectoryNotFound exception.

Please can someone advise how I should reference to the path where my files are built, or point me to a place where I can learn about paths on my build server.

Comment: Are you able to provide your YAML? Are you publishing the pipeline artifact prior to trying to deploy?

Comment: Is the solution provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70593181/unable-to-deploy-a-net-core-app-from-devops-to-azure-using-publish-profile) thread helps you?

Comment: I am publishing the pipeline artifact first. Could you please advise how to get the YAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to deploy/reference built files in Azure DevOps Pipeline?

You need also add the [Publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines.

[image]

Then create a new release pipeline with the build artifact as source artifact:

[image]

Comment: This had me puzzled for days. Thanks so much. I was expecting to be able to do this as part of the pipeline which publishes the build artifacts. There were all these different types of Azure deployment tasks which were so confusing. I now have a whole solution building with several app projects inside. I have a publish artifact task for each project, appropriately named and my release pipeline takes these and deploys to different App Services. Works beautifully, but now I need to work out how to trigger the release pipeline as part of CI/CD.