# Unable to deploy a .NET core app from DevOps to Azure using publish profile

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am creating a new Azure Pipeline to deploy .NET Core API app to an App Service in Azure. I am using `connection type=publish profile` in the pipeline, which is asking for a `.pubxml` file.

I have already committed the .pubxml file in my Azure repository.

[image: .pubxml file committed in repo]

But while giving the path for getting this .pubxml file, I am suspecting that I can't get .pubxml file through build artifacts. Is there any way to get the .pubxml file from azure repos to release pipeline?

[image: Image for pipeline]

I tried with `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\${{ parameters.Location }}\Properties\PublishProfiles\fcmapapi_Dev%20-%20Web%20Deploy.pubxml` but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why I am not getting my question in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add Azure Repos / Build artifact with an alias to your release pipeline.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources---tfvc-git-and-github

Add "Build" resources as an artifact:

[image]

Add "Azure Repository" as an artifact:

[image]

Once, you have added both, the classic release pipeline will look like this:

[image]

Step 2: Use the three dots to browse the files / packages.
[image]

Comment: Hi Tejas, Thanks for your message. While using three dots to browse I am getting only drop folder which is containing deployment files but not .pubxml file. Do i need to add .pubxml file in the drop folder while artifacts being generated by CI? If Yes, How?

Comment: Hello, You can add your repository 2 times.
1st as an artifact, 2nd time as a repository. Then you will have both pubxml files as well your deployable units.

Comment: any example please?

Comment: updated the solution with example, please have a look

Comment: Thanks buddy, but now I am getting error that "No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\_field-connectivity-map-api\ReadDataAPI\Properties\PublishProfiles\fcmapapi_Dev - Web Deploy.pubxml<br/>Check if the package mentioned in the task is published as an artifact in the build or a previous stage and downloaded in the current job."

Comment: This is incorrect path  "D:\a\r1\a_field-connectivity-map-api\ReadDataAPI\Properties\PublishProfiles\fcmapapi_Dev - Web Deploy.pubxml"

It should be like this " D:\a\r1\a\\_field-connectivity-map-api\ReadDataAPI\Properties\PublishProfiles\fcmapapi_Dev - Web Deploy.pubxml"

Comment: Moreover, the solution I have given is for this question that you asked "Is there any way to get the .pubxml file from azure repos to release pipeline?"